# React-DatePicker updating state with previously selected date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I would like to update the state of a component when a date is selected from the React-DatePicker.  I am getting some odd behavior below.

**Example of Current Behavior:**

1. Component loads with empty date field
2. I select 3/28/2017 and get the following console log

   main.ffde8a1f.js:8 it changed dates

   main.ffde8a1f.js:8 date = 1490673600000

   main.ffde8a1f.js:8 dueDate value =
3. Say then I select 3/22/2017 and get the following console log:

   main.ffde8a1f.js:8 it changed dates

   main.ffde8a1f.js:8 date = 1490155200000

   main.ffde8a1f.js:8 dueDate value = 1490673600000

**The second and third logs should have the same value.  Can anyone explain to me why this weird behavior is occurring?**

MY ATTEMPT

**Imports**

```
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
```

**Component**

I set the state of `dueDate` to `''` to begin.

```
export default class Request extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dueDate: '',
    }

    this.handleChangeDate = this.handleChangeDate.bind(this);

  }
```

**Handle Date Selection**

**ISSUE** 
My `handleChangeDate` function will fire when a date is provided and the date in milliseconds will log to the console, but the dueDate is logged as being the previous value it should have been.

```
 handleChangeDate(date) {
    console.log("it changed dates");
    console.log('date = ' + date);  //date in milliseconds logs properly
    this.setState({
      dueDate: date
    });
    console.log('dueDate value = ' + this.state.dueDate);  //date from state logs the previous value rather than its new value
  }
```

**Render**
I am keeping the date picker simple at the moment to minimize potential bugs.  Only the selected date is passed in from the state and the `handleChangeDate` method for a selected date.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="requestDetails">
        <h2>Due Date</h2>
        <DatePicker
           selected={this.state.dueDate}
           onChange={this.handleChangeDate}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: see this ans. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState` is not guaranteed to be synchronous, because they can be processed in batches. This means that although you call `console.log` in your code after your `setState`, the state may not have actually changed yet.

From the React docs:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

If you would like to check if your state is updated, you can either used a callback as the second argument to `setState` or put some logic in the `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` lifecycle method.

Example:

```
handleChangeDate(date) {
  this.setState({
    dueDate: date
  }, () => console.log(this.state.dueDate)); // This will show the updated state when state is set.
}
```

or

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (this.state.dueDate !== nextState.dueDate) {
    console.log('dueDate:  ', nextState.dueDate);
  }
}
```

**setState Documentation:** (Note the function signature, `setState(nextState, callback)`)

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

**shouldComponentUpdate Documentation:**

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: Huge help!  This is great for me to keep in mind for all implementations of setState and logging to make sure it change. Very reusable. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
shouldDidUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        if (this.state.startDate !== nextState.startDate) {
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Use your date in place of startDate

Comment: What is the purpose of this method? It only returns `true` in all the cases. Do you mean that some code has to be but in one of the `if` branches?